# Rbenv: unable to install 2.2.0 or 2.2.1. unable to `gem install bundler` on 2.2.2 (OSX 10.10.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bundler, rbenv

In my attempt to find a solution for this other problem I got frustrated and just removed my Ruby installation with `rm -rf ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2`. Upon reinstalling it with `rbenv install 2.2.2` I've found that suddenly I'm unable to install the `bundler` gem. The `gem install bundler` command results in the following error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Everything I've read seems to indicate that a missing `zlib` package is normally a problem for Linux systems. However, I'm using OSX 10.10.4 and I've read that `zlib` is supposed to come with Command Lines Tools, which I have.

After a bunch of googling and no progress I decided to start over with rbenv. I uninstalled rbenv and reinstalled it but I'm still unable to install bundler with my rbenv installation of ruby 2.2.2. What's more, I've found that I'm unable to install versions 2.2.0 or 2.2.1 at all:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ me$ rbenv install 2.2.0
Downloading ruby-2.2.0.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7671e394abfb5d262fbcd3b27a71bf78737c7e9347fa21c39e58b0bb9c4840fc
Installing ruby-2.2.0...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.10.4 using ruby-build 20150519)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rm/38vbv5g952s54r1txrmrdlf40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150705212307.49958
Results logged to /var/folders/rm/38vbv5g952s54r1txrmrdlf40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150705212307.49958.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from /private/var/folders/rm/38vbv5g952s54r1txrmrdlf40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150705212307.49958/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /private/var/folders/rm/38vbv5g952s54r1txrmrdlf40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150705212307.49958/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems.rb:556:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:717:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:716:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:716:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

I'm totally out of ideas and would appreciate any help if anyone thinks they might know what is going on. My dev environment is pretty much totally hosed at this point.

*EDIT*

Output from running `brew doctor`:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.2209.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.1.5.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.0.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangox-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.2.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.la
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangox-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.a
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
    /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a
    /usr/local/lib/libz.a
```

Comment: Are you also using homebrew? If so could you try running `brew doctor`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MattBrictson. Yes, I have been using homebrew to install/uninstall rbenv and ruby-build. I get some warnings when running `brew doctor` but it doesn't look like anything I haven't seen before. I'll add the full output to my post.

Comment: Hmm I haven't seen those `brew doctor` warnings before. Maybe try moving the `libz*` files out of `/usr/local/lib` to see if that solves things?

Comment: it turns out it was related to my Xcode installation. I've posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that either a) something happened to my Xcode installation (not sure what/how it would've happened) or b) a manual update of Xcode is necessary after upgrade after upgrading OSX.

Even though I had upgraded Command Line Tools I decided to check my Xcode installation in the App Store and noticed that it was possible to install/update. So I did that and then everything worked fine.